# How do I decide how many ViewModels my app should have? Android, MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I see the recommendation is 1 view-model per 1 view (activity, fragment, custom view), but in most examples I see projects only have 1 view-model even though these have multiple views and fragments. Are developers just not following the guideline strictly or am I missing something?

As an example: an app in which there's a section for shopping list items in a recyclerView, and to-do list items in a different recyclerView.

Comment: Where are you seeing this guideline? AFAIK, Google doesn't recommend any specific design pattern for developing on Android. Despite the name, ViewModel isn't intended specifically for the MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on your business logic.

For example one view model for authentication is normal. You have a repository with Api-Interface and Database for example. Then for content of page, It depends on the backend apis and other things. But one thing is recommended and that is you should be aware of SOLID principles specially single-responsibility here. Don't do all your stuffs in one or whatever viewmodels.

You can also see the open-source MVVM repositories and try to simulate the situation for your project.

Comment: Open-source MVVM repositories is what I'm talking about in the project examples I've seen. These usually just have one viewModel. What I'm doing is having 1 viewModel by default (no matter how many views there are), and making more view models if i think it makes sense to me (while considering the Single Responsibility Principle). This way doesn't follow Google's recommendation of 1 viewModel per view, but my way is what I see in most MVVM open source projects. I guess what I'm asking is if it is true developers generally don't follow "1 viewModel per view" rule STRICTLY, because I'm confused.

Comment: <<I guess what I'm asking is if it is true developers generally don't follow "1 viewModel per view" rule>> is exactly true. However, sometimes it is not possible to abide by the rules. In a particular situation, use the best method you can use to solve the problem.